# Cannot enter user through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, chef-infra, vagrant

#### I use Chef recipe to create a user 'app' by the following recipe:

```
user node.app.user do
  password '12345678'
  gid node.app.deploy_group
  home node.app.user_home_path
  shell '/bin/bash'
  supports :manage_home => true
  system true
end

directory "/home/#{node.app.user}/.ssh" do
  action :create
  owner node.app.user
  group node.app.deploy_group
end

template "#{node.app.user_home_path}/.ssh/authorized_keys" do
  source "authorized_keys.erb"
  owner node.app.user
  group node.app.deploy_group
  mode "0644"
end
```

but when I try to enter through ssh

```
$ ssh app@192.168.33.10
$ app@192.168.33.10's password:
$ 12345678
$ Permission denied, please try again.
```

#### I cannot enter not through ssh key, not throug password. What i did wrong?

PS I use vagrant for provisioning (`ssh vagrant@192.168.33.10` is sucsessful)

#### output of: $ ssh -vv app@192.168.33.10 here:

https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/c319e1b3fda884d1cc9e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.password` is actually a password shadow hash ([see docs](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_user.html)). Try getting the hash of your password like that:

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512 12345678 saltsalt
```

and then use obtained string in `user.password`. Additionally linux does not allow to login with *system* users (I am not sure, here), so you should set `system` to `false`.

```
user node.app.user do
  password '$6$saltsalt$9vIXh5xFJESF2.DxxXyWlpOT.0t06Y2Pk11StIw2L8oaOTl42ZfuhPPi5h2PPjbLI.FnnhTBEMMcL05LS2ZmY.'
  system false
  [...]
end
```